# Capture lists: reference to class instance or initialized variable?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

In the [Apple Docs is written the following](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56) on defining a capture list for closures

> Each item in a capture list is a pairing of the weak or unowned
> keyword with a reference to a class instance (such as self) or a
> variable initialized with some value (such as delegate =
> self.delegate!). These pairings are written within a pair of square
> braces, separated by commas.
>
> Place the capture list before a closure’s parameter list and return
> type if they are provided:
>
> ```
> lazy var someClosure: (Int, String) -> String = {
>     [unowned self, weak delegate = self.delegate!] (index: Int, stringToProcess: String) -> String in
>     // closure body goes here
> }
> ```

But what is the exact difference between (1) simply referencing to self or (2) initializing a new variable with self?

```
var someClosure: () -> String = {
  [unowned self]
  // Use self here
}

var someClosure: () -> String = {
  [unowned s = self]
  // Use s here
}
```

Is this new variable modifying the defenition of the original self or is it a new self that shadows the previous one?

Comment: The first let's you use `self` via the keyword `self`, whereas the second lets you access `self` as `s`.

Comment: @AMomchilov So it's a new variable that shadows the previous one and it's not changing the characteristics of the 'original' self?

Comment: It's not shadowing anything. There is no "previous one". And it doesn't directly change anything about the 'original' self, but it it's a reference to the same object, thus changes made to it will effect the original `self` object.

Answer (score 0):

Variable is just a reference some memory location. Depending on the variable type like - weak, strong or unowned, life time of object is decided.

If you use strong variable inside the closure, that closure will take the ownership of object. It lives until closure is there.

If you use weak, until that object is available this will refer to that object. When that object is release, variable is set to nil.

If you use unowned, it will never take ownership of object. Even if the object is released, this will point to that memory.

I explained it here https://medium.com/@rajaths131/life-time-and-scope-of-swift-objects-da7c2e5f4e0f#.uzfy60x9s